# Removing input background colour for Chrome autocomplete?

Tags: autocomplete, input, google-chrome

On a form I'm working on, Chrome is auto-filling the email and password fields. This is fine, however, Chrome changes the background colour to a pale yellow colour.

The design I'm working on is using light text on a dark background, so this really messes up the look of the form - I have stark yellow boxes and near-invisible white text. Once the field is focused, the fields return to normal.

Is it possible to stop Chrome changing the colour of these fields?

Answer (score 1665, accepted):

You can change input box styles as well as text styles inside `input` box:

Here you can use any color e.g. `white`, `#DDD`, `rgba(102, 163, 177, 0.45)`.

But `transparent` won't work here.

```css
/* Change the white to any color */
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover, 
input:-webkit-autofill:focus, 
input:-webkit-autofill:active{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px white inset !important;
}
```

Additionally, you can use this to change the text color:

```css
/*Change text in autofill textbox*/
input:-webkit-autofill{
    -webkit-text-fill-color: yellow !important;
}
```

**Advice:** Don't use an excessive blur radius in the hundreds or thousands. This has no benefit and might put processor load on weaker mobile devices. (Also true for actual, outside shadows). For a normal input box of 20px height, 30px ‘blur radius’ will perfectly cover it.

**Edit 2023:**
To have both transparency and ability to change background color together:

```css
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover, 
input:-webkit-autofill:focus, 
input:-webkit-autofill:active{
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #ffffff;
    transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px 20px #23232329;
}
```

Note that **transition** here does nothing in recent Chrome browsers, it's only a fallback solution for older versions of Chrome.

Comment: In Chrome now the user agent stylesheet shows `:-internal-autofill-previewed` and `:-internal-autofill-selected` pseudoclasses instead of `-webkit-autofill`... Mysteriously however, `-webkit-autofill` still works.  I personally didn't need the `!important`.

Comment: I didn't need the hover/focus/active pseudo selectors

Comment: This dims the highlight for the focus and makes it solid and thin line. Is there a solution for that?

Comment: I think browser able to support background-color customization as the autocomplete color really mess up the design looks , for example material design input

Comment: Thx, it worked for the latest version of Chrome 86, no need for `!mportant`

Comment: Use `-webkit-box-shadow: none` if working with translucent backgrounds and want to remove it altogether.

Comment: The `:active` was the fundamental solution. Tks a lot.

Comment: Just wanted to mention, that the solution for the text works, except that the pipe color remains unchanged, unless you declare also `caret-color: yellow`

Comment: none of them worked for me

Answer (score 420):

I have a better solution.

Setting the background to another color like below didn't solve the problem for me because I needed a transparent input field

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px white inset;
```

So I tried some other things and I came up with this:

```
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
input:-webkit-autofill:active {
    transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, I also need a transparent background. PS: don't forget the `-webkit-text-fill-color: yellow !important;` for text color.

Comment: This will still show the autofill background when the input has been hidden/shown with `display`. [Fiddle - Check it out](https://jsfiddle.net/h4wm1bL2/1/)

Comment: Instead of setting the `transition-duration` ridiculously high, it would be better to set the `transition-delay` instead. That way you reduce even further the possibility of any changes in the colours.

Comment: The `transition` hack will work only if the input is not auto-filled with a default entry recorded by the browser, otherwise the yellow background will still be there.

Comment: Great solution.... but why does this work? And why does setting `background-color` not work? Chrome needs to fix this!!

Comment: I have set an image as background of the input field, this solution removes the yellow shade, but the background image is still hidden

Comment: This one worked for me while the other one don't... For a white background.

Comment: This works for me with the current version of Chrome (55.0.2883.87 m (64-bit)). But I needed to add support for the select control for better coverage. Unfortunately this breaks the compilation of LESS files so I had to add it separately on the page and will eventually include it in the Master Page (asp.net).

Comment: Doesn't work properly if you use WCAG2.0. Change of background on :focus will be distorted. Is there any other solution? The autocomplete behaviour is annoying in Cr.

Comment: Use: `input:-webkit-autofill {
      transition: all 0s 50000s;
    }` to delay all style changes

Comment: in my case I need the same thing for the select, so my final version looks like this:
select:-webkit-autofill,
select:-webkit-autofill:hover,
select:-webkit-autofill:focus,
select:-webkit-autofill:active,
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
input:-webkit-autofill:active {
    transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
}

Comment: Works for Version 89.0.4389.128 (Official Build) (x86_64)

Comment: The max integer is 2147483647s resulting in 68.24 years delay

Comment: Note that this won't work well for dark backgrounds.

Comment: ` transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;` this helps me to solve!

Answer (score 337):

The previous solutions of adding a box-shadow works well for people who need a solid colour background. The other solution of adding a transition works, but having to set a duration/delay will mean that at some point it may show again.

My solution is to use keyframes instead, that way it will always show the colours of your choosing.

```css
@-webkit-keyframes autofill {
    0%,100% {
        color: #666;
        background: transparent;
    }
}

input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s; /* Safari support - any positive time runs instantly */
    -webkit-animation-name: autofill;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
}
```

Example Codepen: https://codepen.io/-Steve-/pen/dwgxPB

Comment: I find this to be better than the accepted answer... the box-shadow method is clever and does work, but when a user is selecting a value to autofill, the default color will briefly flash in the input field, which can be troublesome if your inputs have dark backgrounds.  This solution has no such issues.  Cheers!

Comment: This works for Vuetify 2 especially if you set `color: inherit`

Comment: This used to work for me, but in newest chrome(88) it is not. Any ideas why? And updated solution?

Answer (score 171):

To have a transparent background while not using a time delay (especially needed in modern web applications where people can stop using it for a while and want a predictable behavior of the interface), use this:

```css
input:-webkit-autofill { 
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
}
```

```css
body {
  background: lightblue;
}

input {
  background: transparent;
}

input.no-autofill-bkg:-webkit-autofill {
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="email" />
<input type="text" name="email" class="no-autofill-bkg" />
```

Working on: Chrome 83 / 84.0.4147.89, Edge 84.0.522.44

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work well with inputs with a `background-color` set

Comment: Thanks. Also, does it affect the Bootstrap style in the comment below? @manuel-84
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21401766/box-shadow-not-shown-on-safari-mobile-on-ios-7-in-landscape/51626446#51626446

Comment: @KABA yes of course it will override the background-clip property on webkit, it's still css code so everyone have to study the impact on his codebase

Comment: Awesome, -webkit-background-clip: text; + border-radius:.25rem = round corners

Comment: This is a nice solution, sometimes adding `!important` is necessary.

Comment: To change a color add `-webkit-text-fill-color: white !important;`

Comment: works with mat-form-field thanks man. added color too ` -webkit-text-fill-color: #fff;
          background-clip: text;`

Comment: This + the accepted answer worked for me.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me ~~ July 2023

Comment: This answer should be the accepted one.

Comment: Simple and it worked for me.

Answer (score 105):

### Update 2024

Working after latest updates:

```css
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus {
    transition: background-color 600000s 0s, color 600000s 0s;
}
input[data-autocompleted] {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

Comment: If you're having trouble getting this to work, be sure you don't have another transition set that's overriding this transition on the inputs.

Comment: what about browser support for this?

Comment: safe to use @AzizStark https://caniuse.com/css-transitions

Comment: this works in vivaldi on 18/03/24.. now only if i could get the font to be included... only answer ive found here that works.

Answer (score 86):

This is my solution, I used transition and transition delay therefore I can have a transparent background on my input fields.

```css
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
input:-webkit-autofill:active {
    -webkit-transition: "color 9999s ease-out, background-color 9999s ease-out";
    -webkit-transition-delay: 9999s;
}
```

Comment: I have set an image as background of the input field, this solution removes the yellow shade, but the background image is still hidden

Comment: Best solution so far, works great with existing `box-shadow` for validation

Comment: chrome said `"color 9999s ease-out, background-color 9999s ease-out";` is not valide exprssion. I used code then, `-webkit-transition: background-color 9999s ease-out;` and `-webkit-text-fill-color: #fff !important;`

Comment: @Yoann how exactly did it work with your existing `box-shadow` validation? In my case, due to this css rule, my custom red box shadow (which indicates an input error) gets delayed, making the user believe the most recent input is invalid when in fact it's good.

Answer (score 63):

This has been as designed since this coloring behavior has been from WebKit. It allows the user to understand the data has been prefilled. [Bug 1334](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1334)

You could turn off autocomplete by doing (or on the specific form control:

```
<form autocomplete="off">
...
</form
```

Or you can change the colour of the autofill by doing:

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
    color: #2a2a2a !important;
}
```

Note, there is a bug being tracked for this to work again: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=46543

This is a WebKit behavior.

Comment: thanks but that webkit CSS rule isn't working. The user agent stylesheet is always overruling the background color, even with it (a) set to `!important` and (b) targeted with an ID for higher specificity. It looks like Chrome is always going to override it. Removing autocomplete does seem to work, but it's really not what I want to do.

Comment: Some people have the same issue, did you check the bug post?
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1334

Comment: Chrome blocks any CSS attempts to override that yellow color. Setting `autocomplete="off"` will certainly raise accessibility issues. Why is this answer marked as correct anyway?

Comment: @JoãoRamos That is a Chrome bug, http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=46543

Comment: This is a good solution but if you're using React, it will complain that autocomplete is an unknown DOM property. Therefore, it's actually autoComplete (note camelcased).

Comment: Turning off auto complete is a hack not a solution

Comment: The Chrome bug was marked as WONTFIX in 2019

Answer (score 48):

A possible workaround for the moment is to set a "strong" inside shadow:

```css
input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 0 50px white inset; /* Change the color to your own background color */
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #333;
}

input:-webkit-autofill:focus {
    -webkit-box-shadow: /*your-potential-box-shadow*/, 0 0 0 50px white inset;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #333;
}
```

Comment: This is the solution that is actually working, we do not want to skip the yellow background only some times, as the accepted answer would result in.

Answer (score 27):

try this for hide autofill style

```css
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:active,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus {
    background-color: #FFFFFF !important;
    color: #555 !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px white inset !important;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #555555 !important;
}
```

Comment: for the curious, background-color has no effect. The -webkit-box-shadow is the clever bit that overrides the yellow background in Chrome

Answer (score 26):

After 2 hours of searching it seems google still overrides the yellow color somehow but i for the fix for it. That's right. it will work for hover, focus etc as well. all you have to do is add !important to it.

```css
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
input:-webkit-autofill:active {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px white inset !important;
}
```

this will completely remove yellow from input fields

Answer (score 24):

All of the above answers worked but did have their faults. The below code is an amalgamation of two of the above answers that works flawlessly with no blinking.

```css
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
input:-webkit-autofill:active {
    transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px #fff inset;
}
```

Comment: I have set an image as background of the input field, this solution removes the yellow shade, but the background image is still hidden

Comment: This is the only one working for me in Chrome 83. The most voted one was working 'till Chrome 82.

Answer (score 24):

SASS

```
input:-webkit-autofill

  &,
  &:hover,
  &:focus,
  &:active
    transition-delay: 9999s
    transition-property: background-color, color
```

Comment: This actually worked for me since the accepted answer flashes a pale yellow.

Answer (score 21):

I had an issue where I couldn't use box-shadow because I needed the input field to be transparent. It's a bit of a hack but pure CSS. Set the transition to a very long amount of time.

```css
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
input:-webkit-autofill:active {
    transition: background-color 50000s ease-in-out 0s, color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

Comment: As of now in latest Chrome 50.x.x, IT IS working perfectly fine. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Instead of setting the `transition-duration` ridiculously high, it would be better to set the `transition-delay` instead. That way you reduce even further the possibility of any changes in the colours.

Comment: @Shaggy thanks, I just switched it to a delay. Much nicer.

Answer (score 21):

Adding one hour delay would pause any css changes on the input element. 
This is more better rather than adding transition animation or inner shadow.

```css
input:-webkit-autofill, textarea:-webkit-autofill, select:-webkit-autofill{
  transition-delay: 3600s;
}
```

Comment: Just went through this thread and upvoted all answers with transition-delay, it works perfect and is easy enough to understand if passing the code off to somebody else who has no idea why you put it there.

Answer (score 16):

Try this:
Same as @[Nathan-white](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4395746/nathan-white) answer above with minor tweaks.

```css
/* For removing autocomplete highlight color in chrome (note: use this at bottom of your css file). */

input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
input:-webkit-autofill:active {
    transition: all 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition-property: background-color, color;
}
```

Comment: I like this one best because it means I don't have specifically set my background color or text color again.  (good for my component that is used with a variety of different colors.)  I changed the delay from 0s to 5000s to give it an additional 5000s of being my background color and text color.

Answer (score 12):

In addition to this:

```
input:-webkit-autofill{
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px white inset;
}
```

You might also want to add

```
input:-webkit-autofill:focus{
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px white inset, 0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
}
```

Other wise, when you click on the input, the yellow color will come back. 
For the focus, if you are using bootstrap, the second part is for the border highlighting  0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);

Such that it will just look like any bootstrap input.

Answer (score 12):

This will work for input, textarea and select in normal, hover, focus and active states.

```css
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
input:-webkit-autofill:active,
textarea:-webkit-autofill,
textarea:-webkit-autofill:hover,
textarea:-webkit-autofill:focus,
textarea:-webkit-autofill:active,
select:-webkit-autofill,
select:-webkit-autofill:hover,
select:-webkit-autofill:focus,
select:-webkit-autofill:active {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px white inset !important;
}
```

Here is SCSS version of the above solution for those who are working with SASS/SCSS.

```css
input:-webkit-autofill,
textarea:-webkit-autofill,
select:-webkit-autofill {
    &, &:hover, &:focus, &:active{
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px white inset !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: You brought fun to this question. ♪(^∇^*)

Answer (score 10):

I have a pure CSS solution which uses CSS Filters.

```
filter: grayscale(100%) brightness(110%);
```

The grayscale filter replaces the yellow with grey, then the brightness removes the grey.

[SEE CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/2ne/pen/BJjjaN)

Comment: Ok but as many others solutions this will not allowi to have a transparent background

Answer (score 9):

If you want to keep the autocomplete functionality intact you can use a bit of jQuery to remove Chrome's styling. I wrote a short post about it here:
http://www.benjaminmiles.com/2010/11/22/fixing-google-chromes-yellow-autocomplete-styles-with-jquery/

```
if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("chrome") >= 0) {
$(window).load(function(){
    $('input:-webkit-autofill').each(function(){
        var text = $(this).val();
        var name = $(this).attr('name');
        $(this).after(this.outerHTML).remove();
        $('input[name=' + name + ']').val(text);
    });
});}
```

Comment: This seems to be the best solution, although it blocks [Kicksend's mailcheck](https://github.com/Kicksend/mailcheck). Any ideas on how to work this around?

Comment: This is not a good solution since then google chrome's password auto complete stops working. That is initially you fill in the name and Google chrome auto fills the password. However once the above javascript executes, name gets deleted and set again, and the auto filled password is lost

Answer (score 8):

### 2023 - Transparent background

For transparent input background (light text) on dark background:

```css
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
input:-webkit-autofill:active { 
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #ffffff;
    transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

Comment: I like this answer. But I'd replace `transition` with `-webkit-background-clip: text;`;

Comment: Thank you @Getsumi3, I updated the answer with your contribution. I left the transition part for older browsers as fallback.

Comment: Doesn't work on IOS

Comment: What do you mean? It works just fine on my projects and CodePen https://codepen.io/Marghen23/pen/JjwxByM

Answer (score 7):

I have developed another solution using JavaScript without JQuery. If you find this useful or decide to re-post my solution, I only ask that you include my name. Enjoy. – Daniel Fairweather

```
var documentForms = document.forms;

for(i = 0; i < documentForms.length; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < documentForms[i].elements.length; j++){
        var input = documentForms[i].elements[j];

        if(input.type == "text" || input.type == "password" || input.type == null){
            var text = input.value;
            input.focus();
            var event = document.createEvent('TextEvent');
            event.initTextEvent('textInput', true, true, window, 'a');
            input.dispatchEvent(event);
            input.value = text;
            input.blur();
        }
    }
}
```

This code is based on the fact that Google Chrome removes the Webkit style as soon as additional text is entered. Simply changing the input field value does not suffice, Chrome wants an event. By focusing on each input field (text, password), we can send a keyboard event (the letter 'a') and then set the text value to it's previous state (the auto-filled text). Keep in mind that this code will run in every browser and will check every input field within the webpage, adjust it accordingly to your needs.

Comment: well, it worked for the most part.. it clears my password unfortunately.
Trying to get it to save the password first and reset it after the for loops but chrome seems to be having some issues with that. mmmm

Answer (score 7):

Google Chrome user agent prevent developers' `CSS`, So for changing `autofill` UI must use another property like these:

```css
input:-webkit-autofill,
textarea:-webkit-autofill,
select:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px #d500ff inset !important;
    /*use inset box-shadow to cover background-color*/
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #ffa400 !important;
    /*use text fill color to cover font color*/
}
```

Comment: The `box-shadow` property doesn't need prefixing with `-webkit-` anymore, and it would be more performant to set the size of this to half the height of the input (rather than `1000px`) - where possible, of course. But otherwise, this is unfortunately the best solution to the problem

Answer (score 6):

This works for me to remove the yellow background of the field:

```css
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
input:-webkit-autofill:active,
input:-webkit-autofill:valid,
select:-webkit-autofill,
select:-webkit-autofill:hover,
select:-webkit-autofill:focus {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 99999s;
    -webkit-text-fill-color:#D7D8CE;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I give up!

Since there is no way to change the color of the input with autocomplete I decide to disable all of them with jQuery for webkit browsers. Like this:

```
if (/webkit/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())) {
    $('[autocomplete="on"]').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('autocomplete', 'off');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For those who are using Compass:

```
@each $prefix in -webkit, -moz {
    @include with-prefix($prefix) {
        @each $element in input, textarea, select {
            #{$element}:#{$prefix}-autofill {
                @include single-box-shadow(0, 0, 0, 1000px, $white, inset);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I've got a solution if you want to prevent the autofill from google chrome but its a little bit "machete" , just remove the class that google chrome adds to those inputs fields and set the value to "" if you dont need to show store data after load.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var data = $("input:-webkit-autofill");

        data.each(function (i, obj) {
            $(obj).removeClass("input:-webkit-autofill");
            obj.value = "";
        });
    }, 1);          
});
```

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

```
padding: 5px;
background-clip: content-box;
```

Comment: `background-clip: text;` worked in Chrome

Answer (score 5):

It’s possible to change color of this box, like accepted answer.

But this method is not useful if you want to make the background transparent. However there’s a way (or rather workaround) to make it transparent, like this:

```css
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover, 
input:-webkit-autofill:focus, 
input:-webkit-autofill:active  {
    transition: background-color 5000s;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #fff !important;
}
```

This is basically equivalent to transparent background.

Comment: This is the only one that works in a modern Chrome

Answer (score 4):

Thanks Benjamin!

The Mootools solution is a little more tricky, as I can't get fields by using  `$('input:-webkit-autofill')`, So what I've used is the following:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("chrome") >= 0) {

  window.addEvent('load', function() {
    setTimeout(clearWebkitBg, 20);
    var elems = getElems();
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
      $(elems[i]).addEvent('blur', clearWebkitBg);
    }
  });
}
function clearWebkitBg () {
  var elems = getElems();
  for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    var oldInput = $(elems[i]);
    var newInput = new Element('input', {
      'name': oldInput.get('name'),
      'id': oldInput.get('id'),
      'type': oldInput.get('type'),
      'class': oldInput.get('class'),
      'value': oldInput.get('value')
    });
    var container = oldInput.getParent();
    oldInput.destroy();
    container.adopt(newInput);
  }
}
function getElems() {
  return ['pass', 'login']; // ids
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The solution of Daniel Fairweather ([Removing input background colour for Chrome autocomplete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781549/removing-input-background-colour-for-chrome-autocomplete/9338552#9338552)) (I would love to upvote his solution, but still need 15 rep) works really good. There is a really huge difference with most upvoted solution : you can keep background images ! But a little modification (just Chrome check)

And you need to keep in mind, **it ONLY works on visible fields** !

So you if you are using $.show() for your form, you need to run this code After show() event

My full solution (I have a show/hide buttons for login form ):

```js
if (!self.isLoginVisible()) {
    var container = $("#loginpage");
    container.stop();
    self.isLoginVisible(true);
    
    if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("chrome") >= 0) {
        var documentForms = document.forms;
        
        for (i = 0; i < documentForms.length; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < documentForms[i].elements.length; j++) {
                var input = documentForms[i].elements[j];

                if (input.type == "text" || input.type == "password" || input.type == null) {
                    var text = input.value;
                    input.focus();
                    var event = document.createEvent('TextEvent');
                    event.initTextEvent('textInput', true, true, window, 'a');
                    input.dispatchEvent(event);
                    input.value = text;
                    input.blur();
                }
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    self.hideLogon();
}
```

Sorry again, I would prefer it to be a comment.

If you want, I can put a link to the site where I used it.

Answer (score 4):

None of the solutions worked for me, the inset shadow won't work for me because the inputs have a translucent background overlaid over the page background.

So I asked myself, "How does Chrome determine what should be autofilled on a given page?"

"Does it look for input ids, input names? Form ids? Form action?"

Through my experimentation with the username and the password inputs, there were only two ways I found that would cause Chrome to not be able to find the fields that should be autofilled:

1) Put the password input ahead of the text input. 2) Give them the same name and id ... or no name and id at all.

After the page loads, with javascript you can either dynamically change the order of the inputs on the page, or dynamically give them their name and id ...

And Chrome doesn't know what hit it ... autocomplete is broken!

Crazy hack, I know. But it's working for me.

Chrome 34.0.1847.116, OSX 10.7.5

Answer (score 4):

We can use the `-webkit-autofill` pseudo-selector to target those fields and style them as we see fit. The default styling only affects the background color, but most other properties apply here, such as border and font-size. We can even change the color of the text using `-webkit-text-fill-color` which is included in the snippet below.

```css
/* Change Autocomplete styles in Chrome*/
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover, 
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
textarea:-webkit-autofill,
textarea:-webkit-autofill:hover,
textarea:-webkit-autofill:focus,
select:-webkit-autofill,
select:-webkit-autofill:hover,
select:-webkit-autofill:focus {
    border: 1px solid green;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: green;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px #000 inset;
    transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

Comment: You mentioned font-size: how do I actually change the font-size?
adding `font-size: 24px` doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately strictly none of the above solutions worked for me in 2016 (a couple years after the question)

So here's the aggressive solution I use:

```js
function remake(e){
    var val = e.value;
    var id = e.id;
    e.outerHTML = e.outerHTML;
    document.getElementById(id).value = val;
    
    return true;
}
```

```html
<input id=MustHaveAnId type=text name=email autocomplete=on onblur="remake(this)">
```

Basically, it deletes the tag while saving the value, and recreates it, then puts back the value.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me.

`.input:-webkit-autofill {transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;}`

Comment: This works, though worth noting you don't need the easing or delay: `.input:-webkit-autofill {transition: background-color 5000s}` also works. Alternatively, since the reason that this works is that it just slows down the transition so it's not noticeable, a better solution might be `input:-webkit-autofill { transition: background-color 1s 5000s; }`, as this rather *delays* the transition for that period

Answer (score 3):

and this worked for me (Chrome 76 tested)

```css
input:-internal-autofill-selected {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is complex solution for this task.

```js
(function($){
    if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("chrome") >= 0) {
       $('input, select').on('change focus', function (e) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $.each(
                    document.querySelectorAll('*:-webkit-autofill'),
                    function () {
                        var clone = $(this).clone(true, true);
                        $(this).after(clone).remove();
                        updateActions();
                    })
            }, 300)
        }).change();
    }
    var updateActions = function(){};// method for update input actions
    updateActions(); // start on load and on rebuild
})(jQuery)
```

```css
*:-webkit-autofill,
*:-webkit-autofill:hover,
*:-webkit-autofill:focus,
*:-webkit-autofill:active {
    /* use animation hack, if you have hard styled input */
    transition: all 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition-property: background-color, color;
    /* if input has one color, and didn't have bg-image use shadow */
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px #fff inset;
    /* text color */
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #fff;
    /* font weigth */
    font-weight: 300!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="name" autocomplete="name"/>
<input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="email"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
input:-webkit-autofill {
    border: none;
    border-radius: .3rem;
    caret-color: #fff; /* Pour le I quand on édite */
    color: #fff;
    background: #292a2d;
    /* webkit autofill */
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #fff; /* Surcharge la font color d'autofill */
    -webkit-background-clip: text; /* Supprime le background autofill, utile pour le border radius */
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 50px #292a2d inset; /* Ajoute un fake background à base d'ombrage aplatit */
}
```

Comment: It'd be awfully helpful if your comments **weren't** in French...

Comment: These are in english

`input:-webkit-autofill {
  border: none;
  border-radius: .3rem;
  caret-color: #fff; /* For the I-beam cursor when editing */
  color: #fff;
  background: #292a2d;
  /* webkit autofill */
  -webkit-text-fill-color: #fff; /* Overrides the font color of autofill */
  -webkit-background-clip: text; /* Clips the autofill background to the text, useful for border radius */
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 50px #292a2d inset; /* Adds a fake background using a large inset shadow */
}`

Answer (score 2):

I almost tired all the solutions, but none worked:

but this code worked:

```
input,
select {
  -webkit-background-clip: text !important;
  background-clip: text !important;
}
```

credit: [github link](https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/issues/3860#issuecomment-1177300609)

Comment: Yep! That did it for me too, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before, inset -webkit-box-shadow for me works best.

```
/* Code witch overwrites input background-color */
input:-webkit-autofill {
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px #fbfbfb inset;
}
```

Also code snippet to change text color:

```
input:-webkit-autofill:first-line {
     color: #797979;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although solutions that can be found in many answers do work in *Chrome*, they do not work in *Safari for Mac and iOS*.

*Safari* requires an additional statement – `background-clip`.

This is the full code for a solution that works across all major browsers on different platforms:

```css
/* Disable autofill highlighting */
input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-text-fill-color: var(--text-input-color) !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1rem var(--page-background-color) inset !important;
    background-clip: content-box !important;
}
```

(Please change the `--text-input-color` and `--page-background-color` with your own values.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```css
input:autofill{
    filter:none;
}
```

Basically, the browser just adds it own filters for 'autofill'ed inputs. Your styles go under this.

Answer (score 1):

We have a scenario where in we have a checkbox to enable or disable input fields.

If checkbox is selected the fields will be disabled. Once checkbox is unchecked inputs fields are enabled. We can use chrome autofill to fill those fields like address and all.

On clicking back the checkbox to post autofill the input fields were disabled but Chrome is adding the background to fields populated with autofill In my case those were City, state and zip fields[image]

[image]

[image]

to retain transparency in disabled input fields I had to do

```css
input:disabled:-webkit-autofill,
input:disabled:-webkit-autofill:hover, 
input:disabled:-webkit-autofill:focus, 
input:disabled:-webkit-autofill:active  {
    transition: background-color 5000s;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #fff !important;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    color: white !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, just add,

```
    autocomplete="new-password"
```

to the password field.

Answer (score 0):

use this and check your problem issue is resolved

```
<input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control validate" onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');" readonly>
```

Answer (score -1):

resurrection of thread at two years later. im working around this issue about days and found a simple trick for the prevent this ugly autocomplete feature:

just add a random string to form target like `<form action="site.com/login.php?random=123213">`

it works on recent chrome version 34.0.1847.137

**update:** if it does not work, give strange protocol to action like  `<form id="test" action="xxx://">` and fill this area later with javascript:

```
$('#test').attr('action', 'http://example.site/login.php');
```

**update 2**: still having issues with that, i decided to completely remove the `<form>` tag and post variables via jquery. its more easy.

Comment: Why would you break such patterns users actually ask for?
If you think it is ugly, you should rather make it look prettier. Stop breaking patterns that people might find useful, just because you personally dislike it.

Comment: just wanted to highlight, answer was sent a decade ago. chrome & chromium developers fixed that issue today.

Answer (score -2):

It might be a little late but for future referent there is a CSS ONLY solution as Olly Hodgons shows here 
http://lostmonocle.com/post/1479126030/fixing-the-chrome-autocomplete-background-colour

All you have to do is to add a further selector to overwrite the default input fields setting 
So use instead of

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
    background-color: #FAFFBD !important;
}
```

Somthing like

```
#login input:-webkit-autofill {
    background-color: #ff00ff;
}
```

or

```
form input:-webkit-autofill {
    background-color: #f0f;
}
```

which seems to work fine with me.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working in latest Chrome (01/12/2012) : Version 23.0.1271.95 m

Comment: Downvote reason: Doesn't work in the latest Chrome version (01/04/2013)

Comment: While this should work, it sadly actually doesn't =/

Comment: As of Jan. 2021 all above is ignored for webkit, even if you use !important.