# Background color in input and text fields

Tags: css, html-input

I would like to change the color background in the text and input fields of a form, but when I do this it also affects the submit button! Could it be done in some other way that does not affect the button?

I have used this code:

```
input, textarea {
  background-color: #d1d1d1;
}
```

Comment: As @Damien-at-SF said, use input[type="text"] instead of input. But also use `border: none;` rule to avoid default text input borders.

Answer (score 184, accepted):

```
input[type="text"], textarea {

  background-color : #d1d1d1; 

}
```

**Edit:** working example, http://jsfiddle.net/C5WxK/

Comment: Nice! There is a border effect in the input field, but not the textarea?

Comment: Why did you use both `input[type="text"]` and `textarea` ?

Comment: They are 2 separate tags and need to be addressed separately... `input[type="text"]` doesn't address `textarea` fields.

Comment: Chrome autofill broke it for me. This answer can fix that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781549/removing-input-background-colour-for-chrome-autocomplete

Comment: For some reason, my input fields are only being stylized the moment the page renders. Then, it fades.

Comment: Why does this change the size of my text field?

Answer (score 10):

The best solution is the attribute selector in CSS (`input[type="text"]`) as the others suggested.

But if you have to support [Internet Explorer 6](http://Active%20reading%20[%3Chttps://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_6%3E].), you cannot use it ([QuirksMode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html)). Well, only if you have to  and also are willing to support it.

In this case your only option seems to be to define classes on input elements.

```
<input type="text" class="input-box" ... />
<input type="submit" class="button" ... />
...
```

and target them with a class selector:

```
input.input-box, textarea { background: cyan; }
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to restrict to input fields that are of type text so use the selector `input[type=text]` rather than `input` (which will apply to all input fields (e.g. those of type submit as well)).

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use the button tag with type="submit"

```
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

besides solving your problem, now you can put HTML inside it(icons for example), rather than using the value attribute to set the text.

If you need to insert a normal button inside a form, use type="button" to prevent it submitiing the form