# Change Color of Background Input Field For Autofill Values

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-4, sass, bootstrap-sass

I currently have a Rails 4 application running bootstrap-sass for Bootstrap 2.  I use localhost for my testing.  I have applications with a login screen.  The input fields are white with a really thin gray border with blue text.  When I type in the fields the background of the input fields are white with blue text.  However when I go to the login screen where I have saved my login information the information fills up the fields but changes the background of both fields to yellow with the text black.  One is text-field and the other is password-field.

I would like the information to fill in using the css I have defined in the view.  Is there a way I can do this with CSS?  I have not found anything with this specific issue.

Any help would be appreciated.  I will continue searching.

**UPDATE 3/28/2014 9:15 am CDT**

I successfully implemented the solution from the link that was suggested by Martin to change the background color for autofill.  I decided to guess and did a search on webkit font color text and found the solution to change the font color for autofill.

Here is my solution:

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: $textColor;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px white inset;
}
input:-moz-autofill {
  -moz-text-fill-color: $textColor;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px white inset;
}
input:-o-autofill {
  -o-text-fill-color: $textColor;
  -o-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px white inset;
}
input:-khtml-autofill {
  -khtml-text-fill-color: $textColor;
  -khtml-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px white inset;
}
```

Comment: sounds like Chrome autocomplete - you wnat to look into it - this might give you some ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781549/removing-input-background-colour-for-chrome-autocomplete

Comment: Martin, that worked.  Please add it as an answer and I will check it.  My background is white now.  The text is black.  I would like to find a way to change the color but for now that is not as important as changing the background color which fits my color scheme.

Answer (score 4):

I had to extend your solution to address the input fields on :focus as well. This code currently works for my needs:

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-text-fill-color: $black;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px white inset;
}
input:-moz-autofill {
    -moz-text-fill-color: $black;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px white inset;
}
input:-o-autofill {
    -o-text-fill-color: $black;
    -o-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px white inset;
}
input:-khtml-autofill {
    -khtml-text-fill-color: $black;
    -khtml-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px white inset;
}

input:focus:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-text-fill-color: $black;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px white inset;
}
input:focus:-moz-autofill {
    -moz-text-fill-color: $black;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px white inset;
}
input:focus:-o-autofill {
    -o-text-fill-color: $black;
    -o-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px white inset;
}
input:focus:-khtml-autofill {
    -khtml-text-fill-color: $black;
    -khtml-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px white inset;
}
```

Comment: Good answer but you can reduce the amount of code you need by using the same `{}` section for each browser support query. All you need to do is `input:-webkit-autofill, input:focus:-webkit-autofill {`.