# How to stop yellow background on input field focus?

Tags: css

A form I've made turns yellow when you click in it, though I didn't set it yellow. Is this standard?

I've deleted all of the project's css, and the yellow still appears.

So I tried forcing the color like so

```
#siteSearch.active {
background-color: #fff;
}
```

I've not come across this before - anyone else encountered it?

Cheers

Comment: Depending on the browser, Chrome presumably, it's likely you're seeing the 'auto-complete' functionality that is making the input background yellow. In which case you'll need to turn off the setting in order for the yellow background to stop appearing on focus.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing input background colour for Chrome autocomplete?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781549/removing-input-background-colour-for-chrome-autocomplete)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is likely happening in other browsers as well. As Shaun has stated it is likelty due to auto-complete. Safari also highlights input fields yellow (on mobile and desktop). This could be why.

This answer seems to be what you're looking for:

[Removing input background colour for Chrome autocomplete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781549/removing-input-background-colour-for-chrome-autocomplete)

Comment: Thanks guys, but neither solution worked. It's happening in all browsers too, IE included. I don't think this it's autocomplete that's doing it in this case, as the form isn't auto-completing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. If gives a colorless/white background to input fields an to all possible psudeo classes that can throw the error...

```css
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:active,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus {
    background-color: #FFFFFF !important;
    color: #555 !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px white inset !important;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #555555 !important;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).