# Can't get rid of green background for form input

Tags: html

I have a form that keeps coloring an input background green, even though I seem to have done everything I can to make it white:

[image]

HTML
[image]

Chrome Computed Style
[image]

Does anyone understand what's going on?

Thanks

Comment: where is green color in image??

Comment: plugins. lastpass or something?

Comment: This is browser stuff as it is stored your password

Comment: No offense, but in my country it is called yellow.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781549/removing-input-background-colour-for-chrome-autocomplete

Comment: To me it looks light green. In any case, it's 250, 255, 189.  "This is browser stuff as it stores your password."  No.  It does the same thing for the email field. There are no plugins or "lastpass" that I know of. Looking briefly at Sujit's link, I think the answer is there. I'll jump on it tomorrow. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use simple CSS style to fix it.

```
.password:hover,.password:focus,.password:target,.password:active{
    background:#fff;
}
```