# How to change the style of :-webkit-autofill?

Tags: css, google-chrome, web

The default background-color of the `:-webkit-autofill` is orange. How to change it?

```
:-webkit-autofill, input:-webkit-autofill {
    background-color: #fff !important;
}
```

The above code doesn't work.

Comment: More info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781549/removing-input-background-colour-for-chrome-autocomplete

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not `background-color` that gets rid of that yellow/orange, it's the `box-shadow`:

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 100px #fff inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 100px #fff inset;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 100px #fff inset;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cah change the background-color for autofilled inputs using `box-shadow`

For Firefox you need additionally `filter:none`.

```css
:-webkit-autofill { /* -webkit also works in firefox here */
    filter:none; /* needed for firefox! */
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 100px rgba(38, 163, 48, 0.212) inset;
}
```

How and if this works with Safari I don't know.