# Disable autofill forms with React and Material UI

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-design, material-ui

I am trying to learn React and Material UI.

I am creating a web form and so far everything is good, except when the page loads, chrome auto fills the text fields with previously stored data and the background changes to yellow. How can I keep it at white?

I know in normal CSS I would include this code:

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px white inset;
}
```

However given that this I do not necessarily have a style sheet this presents an issue.

I have so far:

```
const MyAwesomeReactComponent = React.createClass({
const containerStyle = 
    {
      /* input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px white inset;
          } */
    };
 return (
      <div style={containerStyle}>
           <form action="/login" method="post" autocomplete ="off">
              <div>
                  <TextField hintText="Email Field" floatingLabelText="Email"  underlineFocusStyle={{borderColor: Colors.amber900}} />
              </div>
              <div>
                  <TextField hintText="Password Field" floatingLabelText="Password" type="password" />
              </div>
              <div>
                  <RaisedButton label="Submit" primary={true}/>
              </div>
          </form>
});
module.exports = MyAwesomeReactComponent;
```

I am getting a Syntax error while parsing through the `input-webkit-autofill` code.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to write css in javascript, you have to turn dashed-key-words into camelCaseKeys

For example:

- `background-color` => `backgroundColor`
- `border-radius` => `borderRadius`

but vendor prefix starts with capital letter (except `ms`)

- `-webkit-box-shadow` => `WebkitBoxShadow` (capital W)
- `-ms-transition` => `msTransition` ('ms' is the only lowercase vendor prefix)

see [the react doc #inline-styles section](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/inline-styles.html) for more details

So in your example:

```js
const containerStyle = {
  WebkitBoxShadow: '0 0 0 1000px white inset'
};
```

Now, because inline styles gets attached on tags directly instead of using selectors, we have to put this style on the `<input>` tag itself, not the container.

To override the `<input>` style of `<TextField>`, use the `inputStyle` prop [documented here](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/text-fields)

***EDIT:***
But doing this, you'll lose the hint text, because it will be covered by the box-shadow. Adding `z-index` to the hint text can fix this!

so finally your example will be like this:

```js
const hideAutoFillColorStyle = {
  WebkitBoxShadow: '0 0 0 1000px white inset'
};
const hintStyle = { zIndex: '1' };

<div>
  <TextField
    hintText="Email Field"
    floatingLabelText="Email"
    underlineFocusStyle={{borderColor: Colors.amber900}}
    inputStyle={hideAutoFillColorStyle}
    hintStyle={hintStyle} />
</div>
<div>
  <TextField
    hintText="Password Field"
    floatingLabelText="Password"
    type="password"
    inputStyle={hideAutoFillColorStyle}
    hintStyle={hintStyle} />
</div>
```

---

Note: react inline styles have some limitations, such as `@media` queries. To get around this, you can use `<style>` tags:
See [this article](https://medium.com/@jviereck/modularise-css-the-react-way-1e817b317b04#.rvjofqs9z) for more examples!

BTW you can use some [autoprefixer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/autoprefixer#css-in-js) (such as [post-css](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-js)) to do the prefixing job for you.

Comment: since putting `zIndex: 1` on hintText blocks the click event to propagate to the input element, which makes it hard to click and get focus on the input, I found a better way than using the `WebkitBoxShadow` method: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29350537/4997172 just put them in CSS and forget about the yellow background (you can remove both `inputStyle` and `hintStyle` now!).

Answer (score 1):

You can add a CSS file with the input pseudo styles and give the container div  className. You should include the file in your SPA html.

E.g. the CSS file...

```
.formcontainer input:-webkit-autofill { -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px white inset; }
```

Then in your render code -

```
<div className="formcontainer"><form ...>
```

And don't forget to include the CSS file in your html page!

Apologies for bad indentation, I'm using SO app.

Comment: could you provide an example?