# CSS change inputed fields background-color?

Tags: css

I wrote a user login page, but I can not change inputted fields backgound color.

```
.form-signin-row {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 51px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 19px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    background-color: #F0EEF0;
    border: 1px solid #DCDCDC;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,-webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
}
```

Like this:

[image]

I found "user agent stylesheet":

```
input:-webkit-autofill, textarea:-webkit-autofill, select:-webkit-autofill {
    background-color: rgb(250, 255, 189);
    background-image: none;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

**Just chrome cached my username and password, NOT work. If I clear cached, work well.**

I try to override:

```
input:-webkit-autofill, textarea:-webkit-autofill, select:-webkit-autofill { 
     background-color: #fff;
}
```

still not work:

[image]

Comment: not the same problem. @aug

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781549/removing-input-background-colour-for-chrome-autocomplete)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the same class to override the default styles of the chrome browser (that behaviour is a big crap to designers)

```
input:-webkit-autofill, textarea:-webkit-autofill, select:-webkit-autofill { 
     background-color: #fff !important;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px white inset;
}
```