# Search type input field - How to remove highlight color from previous search

Tags: html, css, input, highlight, box

So, basically. I have a search type input field. This is a searchbox, when you double click the input box you can see all your previous searched keywords and when you select or hover over a keyword the background changes color from white to yellow. Like shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

I would like to disable this highlight color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is google auto-complete, check out the top answer in this post [Removing input background colour for Chrome autocomplete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781549/removing-input-background-colour-for-chrome-autocomplete)

Answer (score 4):

I think you could use this few lines in your CSS :

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px white inset;
}
```

And to change the text color :

```
-webkit-text-fill-color: yellow !important;
```