# Form input adds background when autocompleted

Tags: css

[image]

How I can remove an ugly input background who wildly appears only when the form is autocompleted?

Comment: Use google first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781549/removing-input-background-colour-for-chrome-autocomplete

Answer (score 1):

`input:-webkit-autofill` 
(with/without pseudo classes) will select autocompleted inputs.

`-webkit-text-fill-color: color !important;` will set the text color