# What is the maximum value of a CSS transition's duration?

Tags: css, max, css-transitions, duration

What is the maximum value of duration in CSS [`transition-duration`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#transition-duration-property) or [`transition-delay`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#transition-delay-property) property?
I can't find this information.

I found only that default value is `0s`.

I used these documents:

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions
2. https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transitions/
3. https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/
4. https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#time-value

Comment: Since it is in `seconds`, there is no limit until the longest integer.. But more the number, it is waste to implement it.. :)

Comment: @GuruprasadRao thanks for quick reply!

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)

Comment: BTW I interested in it because I need solution for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781549/removing-input-background-colour-for-chrome-autocomplete/29350537#29350537 and I can not use box-shadow because my inputs have transparent background. I have to preserve transparency.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao that would be milliseconds, so the time in seconds would be a factor 1000 less. Still a lot of seconds though...

Comment: @MrLister Is it so? cos I see it be assigned as 1s 2s etc which basically means seconds!! Correct me if am wrong..

Comment: @Danix.. Couldn't get your requirement though, would be good if you add it as detailed ques or edit your OP..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao See the OP's last link. Times can be expressed in `s` or `ms`. And when using `s`, you can specify fractions, like `1.5s`.

Comment: Oh.. Alright.. :) That's pretty neat enough..

Comment: I don't know, but I just stumbled upon CSS support for scientific notation (`1e9s`) and it seems to be working in both Firefox and Chromium.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Guruprasad J Rao mentioned, the longest transition-duration possible is the number of seconds contained within the largest integer possible, which happens to be **2147483647**.  If anybody is curious, a transition-duration of 2147483647s is 68.24 *years* (including leap years).

This sounds ridiculous, I agree. However, there actually are use cases for this.  For example, in my own project, I ran into a problem where webkit didn't let me change the background color of their browser-implemented input autofill.  Overriding via "!important" didn't work because browser-implement styles are impossible to override like that.  So, to stop the webkit autofill from changing my input's colors, I just used `transition: background-color 2147483647s`.  Problem solved.