# Make input backgroundcolor to transparent for autofill

Tags: angularjs, html, css

I want make the saved input text box background to be transparent
[Please click for the default format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bk9Og.png)

[Please click for what i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDbJJ.png)

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781549/removing-input-background-colour-for-chrome-autocomplete

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow - please show your work so far, and try to give a minimal example of the issue you are facing, with a good explanation.

Comment: Please show your source.