# .class prefix on input:-webkit-autofill is not honored

Tags: css, css-selectors

Using the answer from [Removing input background colour for Chrome autocomplete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781549/removing-input-background-colour-for-chrome-autocomplete) I would like to disable the autofill background color but only on specific forms.

```
.myform input:-webkit-autofill,
.myform input:-webkit-autofill:focus {
    -webkit-transition: color 9999s ease-out, background-color 9999s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 9999s;
}
```

Html:

```
<form class="myform" method="POST" action="targetpage.aspx">
    <input type="text" name="Username">
    <input type="password" name="Password">
</form>
```

But the above is not honored (e.g. in Chrome).
Adding `.myform` makes it fail.
Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Comment: Is the `.myform` class added to the `form` tag or to the `input` tag? If input, your selector would be `input.myform`

Comment: Please include your HTML.

Comment: The .myform class is on the form itself.
So HTML is:

`<form class="myform" method="POST" action="targetpage.aspx">
<input type="text" name="Username">
<input type="password" name="Password">
</form>`

Comment: This is working for me, tested here: http://jsbin.com/xedajoroxu/1/edit?html,css,output . The first form autofill does not have the yellow background.