# Chrome Autocomplete - Remove background style when record saved

Tags: google-chrome, textinput

Is it possible to force Chrome to remove the autocomplete background style for a text input once the record has been saved?

```
<input type="text" id="fltrName" class="form-control" ng-model="calEvtFilter.name" />
```

When a user types an entry that has previously been used then saves the record the autocomplete style remains.  The only way I can remove the style at the moment is to reset the form then populate the angularJS model with the data again?

Comment: I didn't find a way to remove the background colour entirely however the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781549/removing-input-background-colour-for-chrome-autocomplete?rq=1) removes the backgound colour when the user moves off the input field.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can remove the autofill settings from your Chrome Setting

Go to Chrome **Settings** -> Click on **Show Advanced Setting**

Uncheck *Enable Autofill to fill out web forms in a single click*  under **Passwords and Forms**

Close the chrome and open again

Comment: Thanks Rajender but I don't want to disable autocomplete I just want to remove the background color of the text input once the record has been saved.