# Html input form styling on dropdown list hover

Tags: html, css, wordpress, dropdown

I have a wordpress page with simple html search input form:

```
<!-- ROW :: START - SEARCH -->
<div class="htheme_row_search">
<div class="htheme_container">
    <div class="htheme_col_12">
        <form action="http://www.someurl.com/" method="get">
            <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Czego szukasz?">
            <div class="htheme_icon_search_btn"></div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- ROW :: END - SEARCH -->
```

and it looks like this:

[image: search_input]

But when I click on it or start typing it shows dropdown list of previously searched phrases. And when I hover the mouse over the phrase my search bar changes it's background color and looks like this:

[image: search_input_on_hover]

I can't find any style in the css that might be responsible for this. How can I fix it so it won't change the color?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing input background colour for Chrome autocomplete?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781549/removing-input-background-colour-for-chrome-autocomplete)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `autocomplete="off"` to your input element

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" value="" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Czego szukasz?">
```