# Disable ugly yellow highlights in input fields. html css

Tags: html, css, highlight

Would someone be kind enough as to point me in the right direction to remove this annoying, ugly yellow highlights that browsers seem to display in your beautifully designed input fields?

I'd like to remove it from all major browsers.

Thank you so much!

Richard.

[image]

Comment: it's because you have saved your details on the browser cache

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781549/removing-input-background-colour-for-chrome-autocomplete

Answer (score -1):

try the following in css:

```
input[type="text"]
{
    background:white;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replaying, that's not what I'm looking for. The background is already set to white. However, the browser automatically recognizes that you visited this website before knows which username and password you used so it places the credentials in there along with that yellow background.

Comment: @RichardRodgers Alright. I got it. You are looking for change in color after auto-complete. Sorry, I got it wrong.