# input text background color is set as yellow, only in chrome

Tags: html, css

input text background color is set as yellow, only in chrome. How to remove this color?

[image]

I already tried to set background-color and everything but is still yellow

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing input background colour for Chrome autocomplete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781549/removing-input-background-colour-for-chrome-autocomplete)

Comment: its default chrome autoslect bg color so you cant change this

Comment: can you upload here that what you tried or upload your css.

Answer (score 4):

Either turn `autocomplete` off by adding the `autocomplete="off"` attribute to your HTML element, or use CSS:

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px white inset;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's yellow as chrome's default filled-in-color for auto-filled elements is yellow. Default browser CSS:

```
input:-webkit-autofill, textarea:-webkit-autofill, select:-webkit-autofill {
    background-color: rgb(250, 255, 189);
    background-image: none;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

So, change yellow to any other color like this:

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 500px white inset;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set autocomplete="false" otherwise set Background color for input box

Answer (score -1):

This background color is set because of Browser's auto-fill property for username and password.

You can use `autocomplete = 'off'` attribute for this, just set this in you input tag.

Or you can use below css for this:

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px white inset;
}
```

Or you can use jquery for this like below:

```
$('#input_id').attr('autocomplete', 'off');
```