# Transparent input field changes to a yellowish when autocompleted

Tags: html, css

at the moment I'm creating simple forms for login and registration purposes. The style is changed to a transparent background and I created a floating label. So far so good, everything is working perfectly fine.

[image]

When I input some data manually, the label is getting smaller and goes to the top as wanted, and the background stays transparent.

[image]

But here is the problem. Although auto-complete is switched off, there is an auto-complete option made by my browser.
If I'm selecting the suggestion for the input field, it somehow switches to a yellowish color.

[image]

Any ideas where this is coming from and how I can prevent this from happening ?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can overwrite this with the following CSS:

```
input,
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus {
    background-color: transparent!important;
}
```

On Google Chrome you should do the following:

```
input,
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px red inset;
}
```

More information about removing the autocomplete color in Google Chrome here: [Removing input background colour for Chrome autocomplete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781549/removing-input-background-colour-for-chrome-autocomplete)

You can avoid the flash up of the yellow background on selecting the autocomplete-value by adding `input` to the CSS rules.

Comment: I added both lines to my CSS and it works nearly perfect. When I click and the field is getting autocompleted, the yellow color/nackground flashes up for a splitsecond in a weird way, but in the end it is transparent