# Can't able to change Email and Password input element background color Shopify

Tags: css, shopify

I'm in the really big problem I cant able to change Email and Password input element background color in Shopify site in both login and register page.

I just realized that the problem is only in chrome only.

Comment: What have you tried so far? I was able to do so by using an inline rule with !important

Comment: @arielnmz I tried this `background-color: #000 !important;` in inline rule but it does not change for email and password else its working

Comment: @arielnmz check it in chrome

Comment: i got it what was the problem please delete your answers so i can able to delete this stupid question. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting this in your css, it should override the current styles...

```css
input[type="text"],
input[type="search"],
input[type="password"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="file"],
input[type="number"],
input[type="tel"],
textarea,
select {
  background-color: #ff9900;
}
```

**However**

if its auto-complete thats only happening in chrome then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781549/removing-input-background-colour-for-chrome-autocomplete) should fix it:

You can use any color e.g. white, #DDD, rgba(102, 163, 177, 0.45).

```
/* Change the white to any color ;) */
input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px white inset;
}
```

Additionally, you can use this to change the text color:

```
/*Change text in autofill textbox*/
input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-text-fill-color: yellow !important;
}
```

Comment: I did it, refresh and look at what happen.

Comment: @RajnishCoder yeah you will have to change the `background-color: #` to the color you want - you can get one from here https://www.google.com/search?q=hex+color&oq=hex+col&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.2611j1j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 :)

Comment: I know that but the problem is only in chrome

Comment: @RajnishCoder is it showing yellow because its auto completing?

Comment: yes thank you so much, i got that too but here is the real question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781549/removing-input-background-colour-for-chrome-autocomplete
so help me to delete this question

Comment: @RajnishCoder ah okay you can just mark this as the correct answer then if it fixed your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity):

> Specificity is the means by which browsers decide which CSS property
>   values are the most relevant to an element and, therefore, will be
>   applied

The browser assings a weight based on the selector types that arre applied to the same element, the one with the bigger weight gets applied, so in your case the selector `#customer_login input[type="email"]` has a bigger weight than even an inline style, so adding `!important`  to your rule does the trick here (taken from the [same topic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)):

> When an important rule is used on a style declaration, this
>   declaration overrides any other declarations

TL;DR This does the trick:

```
background-color: red !important;
```