# Why autocomplete removes textbox image

Tags: javascript, html, css, autocomplete

I have a simple login page in html with two textboxes and with icons in them. When I fill the textbox with autocomplete data, the icon hides and the textbox color becomes yellow. Why is that happening. Please help me ?

Here's the snapshot of the login page:

[image]

[image]

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body style="background-color:#f5f5f5;font-family:Tahoma;"

<div class="login_div">
    <div style="height:20px;width:240px;background-color:#00b300;"><span style="color:white;margin-left:10px">Secure Login</span></div>
    <form id="frm" action="check_login.php" method="post">
        <input class="in_box1" name="username" type="text" placeholder="Username/Email" title="Enter Username or Email" maxlength="20" required>
        <input class="in_box2" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" title="Enter Password" maxlength="10" required>
        <input style="margin-left:25px;font-size:15px;" type="checkbox" title="Enter Password">
        <span style="font-size:14px;">Remember Me</span><br>
        <input class="in_btn" type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8v21wmbf/1/ ..here's the jsfiddle of the same but it doesn't have any images.

Comment: This may help --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781549/removing-input-background-colour-for-chrome-autocomplete

Comment: that just changes the textbox background color to white and removes the image

Comment: It's better to create a new span class for your icon.
Because even you change auto-fill still your icon will be change.
Or better do autocomplete="off" for your inputbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We should use bootstrap to solve this.
Check This:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<form id="frm" action="check_login.php" method="post">
   <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">(your icon)</span>
      <input class="in_box1" name="username" type="text" 
         placeholder="Password" title="Enter Username or  Email" maxlength="20" 
         required/>
   </div>
   <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">(your icon)</span>
      <input class="in_box2" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password"
         title="Enter
         Password" maxlength="10" required/>
   </div>
</form>
```

I hope This would be helpful.
https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/input-group/

The JsFiddle link is :
https://jsfiddle.net/6ugek6qw/

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle for the same?

Comment: I have added the fiddle.

Comment: Not got what I was looking for, but accepting the answer for other solution and for learning something new!!