# How Do I Get Rid Of The Yellow Auto Complete Filler in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this search box on my website, chrome suggests past searches. However, it dye's the search box yellow. I have tried to suggest ways to fix this and nothing works. However When I paste my code back in the sources tab of inspect element it works! I believe chrome is replacing my code, and then inspect replaces theirs, however, I don't know how to stop it from replacing mine.

I am trying to get rid of the yellow, not fully delete the autocomplete feature.

My Code Looks Like: [image] However Chrome Inspect Element Sources Looks Like: [image]

```css
input[type=text]:-webkit-autofill {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 100px white inset;
}
```

```html
<div class="Search1">
  <div class="inputWithIcon">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Channel ID" id="chnlname" class="Input2" :-webkit-autofill></input>
    <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true" id="update"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thats what I am currently using.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disabling Chrome Autofill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill)

Comment: @ShubhamGupta No, as I am not trying to disable it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be the `:active` state is causing the yellow. Credit to [Nathan White](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29350537/9097381) for this trick:

```
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
input:-webkit-autofill:active {
    transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```