# Angular Material - force chrome autofill to paint whole input

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular-material

I'm using a Angular Material 6.0.4 I stumbled upon a problem.
I got form for basic user data if user use chrome autofill to fill the data the data got injected properly however it leaves yellow(blue) background. 
Due to the way material angular is made. Colored is only strip of whole input component.

Is there a way to make chrome fill whole input component?

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e4vngp)

Here's what I got:

[image: Here's what i got]

Here's what I want (i used paint):

[image]

Comment: You can use some properties like in this [exemple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781549/removing-input-background-colour-for-chrome-autocomplete)

Comment: I don't want to remove background colour. I want it to fill whole div.

Comment: I know but you can use the exemple to change the width, the height border-box, try other css properties etc.. try to add height and width to 100% for exemple

Comment: did you find a solution?