# How to change color of prefilled text input html?

Tags: html, css, materialize

I need to change green background color from text input in below picture:

[image: prefilled text input]

This color only shows when prefilled value loaded in text input or user choose from autocomplete suggestions. So when user types in this box, background is white.
I need to this box always white.

Comment: Already been answered on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781549/removing-input-background-colour-for-chrome-autocomplete