# How to change input name background?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, scss-lint

When I click the mouse on input, Drop down the mailing list, When I bring the mouse to Miles Is changing input background. As shown in the photo.
How to remove or change this time input background?

[image]

I have already tried "focus", But it didn't work.

```
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">

    input {
        background: none;

        &:focus {
            background: none;
        }
    }
```

Comment: try maybe adding the `!important` in your css

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre], and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Google chrome you can do the following:

```css
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover, 
input:-webkit-autofill:focus, 
input:-webkit-autofill:active  {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px white inset !important;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="name">
```

Replace `white` for the desired color. I took this snippet from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14205976/11755228). It should also be a good idea to take a deeper look into that SO question has there are slightly different solutions that might work better for you.

Keep in mind that this is non standard and its use should be avoided but for now, this is what you can do.
Ref: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:-webkit-autofill)

Comment: but if i need that background none?

Comment: I don't think you can, only choose a color that will give that impression.

Answer (score 0):

```
input:hover {
   background-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: if you want to remove box shadow then add `box-shadow: none;`