# Google Chrome autofill background color change?

Tags: css, google-chrome, autocomplete, webkit

I'm trying to get the autofill background color on my inputs changed.

The accepted answers online seem to be something along the lines of:

[Removing input background colour for Chrome autocomplete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781549/removing-input-background-colour-for-chrome-autocomplete)

```
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover, 
input:-webkit-autofill:focus, 
input:-webkit-autofill:active,
input:-internal-autofill-selected,
input:-internal-autofill-previewed {
    background-color: white !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px white inset !important;
}
```

This seems to work accept in one situation, which is when the fields are already auto filled.

Meaning I refresh the browser and the fields are already pre-filled with a username/password.

When I hover over or click in the input the background color changes. However when I do nothing the `box-shadow` as no effect and it's still set to the default `user agent stylesheet`.

```
input:-internal-autofill-selected {
    background-color: rgb(232, 240, 254) !important;
    background-image: none !important;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0) !important;
}
```

I've also tried some random properties with no success.

```
input:-internal-autofill,
input:-internal-autofill:hover, 
input:-internal-autofill:focus, 
input:-internal-autofill:active,
```

Chrome Version 77.0.3865.90 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Can't figure out how to override this at all. It's like it's been added at the bottom of the css rules with an `important` so impossible to override?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Box shadow work for me try below code. You can change the shadow color as per your requirment.

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
    background-color: transparent !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 50px white inset;
}
```

[image: Inspect Element]