# Chrome autocomplete background-color

Tags: html, css

It seems that the current way to change the background-color of an input that is autofilled (username is my example bellow) by the browser is by using a `transition`:

```
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
input:-webkit-autofill:active {
    transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #fff !important;

}

#input-container input{
    display: block;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

This is working but is there any cleaner way to do it whiteout having to create a transition?

[image: example form]

Comment: `transition` does not change the background color. That's what `background-color` is for. `transition` just creates an animation when a property changes.

Comment: This is not what I am saying. transition has to be on the code for most of the solutions. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781549/removing-input-background-colour-for-chrome-autocomplete

Comment: I see, that makes more sense.

Answer (score -3):

```css
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
input:-webkit-autofill:active  {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px white inset !important;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. Future readers will be grateful to see explained *why* it answers the question instead of having to infer it from the code.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).