# Change CSS style for autocomplete search options

Tags: css, autocomplete, inputbox

I have an input box customized to have an orange text.

[image: input box orange value]

When I have autocomplete options, I managed to make the input text orange, but only for the final value from the input box.

```
input:-webkit-autofill:active[type=input] {
    -webkit-text-fill-color: orange !important;
}
```

What I want is to have an orange option also in the selector, before clicking on it in order to populate the input box. Now it's still black.

[image: option for input box]

How can I change the color for that suggested "1" to be also orange?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing input background colour for Chrome autocomplete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781549/removing-input-background-colour-for-chrome-autocomplete)

Comment: @Jax-p , no. That changes the CSS for the input box itself, not for the option that I will select to populate my input box.