# Disable browser's yellow auto fill

Tags: html, css, web

I've been searching for this all over the internet, however i haven't found any working solution yet.

I've been unable to find any fix on how to get rid of the terrible ugly yellow auto fill color.
i tried multiple things, of whom the most common "fix" to this is the `input:-webkit-autofill:hover` thing, however this does not work.

How does one actually fix this?

Also why the hell do the people think this is a good idea for a autofill feature?!

[image: Colors]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing input background colour for Chrome autocomplete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781549/removing-input-background-colour-for-chrome-autocomplete)

Comment: It does not, for that's the same solution i mentioned not working

Comment: It worked for me, can you check the linkage of your CSS properties once again, you might be messing up with the name of the selector or so, just a guess because the same CSS properties worked fine for me

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of trouble i've found a solution.

```css
input {
    filter: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either turn off autocomplete or use the onchange attribute and set the background colour to white

Answer (score 0):

Use the `autocomplete="off"` attribute

Comment: That wasn't the question