# Change input background color not working

Tags: css, antd

I'm using antd input like this
[image]

How to change the grey color to white color.
I tried changing on the input tag:

`background-color: white !important`;

but it doesn't work

Comment: Please post your HTML and CSS

Answer (score 4):

This is because of autocomplete, which sets a blue background on these elements. You can use a quick hack to fix this, using an inset box-shadow:

```css
input:-webkit-autofill {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 9999px #fff inset;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would like to ask if that happened when the **input** is focused? Can you try this

```
input[type=password]:focus {
    background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a style when the input is selected.

Try to :focus

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot looks like password field was filled by autocomplete.
If my guess is right, please head to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill) and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781549/removing-input-background-colour-for-chrome-autocomplete).