# How to change the size and style of the suggested search terms which opens under the search bar based on the search history?

Tags: javascript, html, css, search-box

**Background:** I wrote a search box like a google search box. However, when I want to search a word, a box opens automatically under the search box, suggesting words based on the history of the words typed in that box. I have not coded the box for the suggestions; it is a browser's feature. The size, shape, and style of the box that provides the suggestions depend on the choice of browser.

**Problem:** I want to style this box without deactivating the browser suggestion box. In other words, I need to make the width, shape (curves) and shading proportional to the search box that I coded. I am looking only for pure CSS, HTML, and Vanilla Javascript solutions if this is possible at all.

An example is how Google has done it (please see the screenshot):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8ryM.jpg)

If this is not possible, then I have to code everything myself. In that case, how can I have access to the history of the previous words which the browser stores?

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781549/removing-input-background-colour-for-chrome-autocomplete).

You need to use input:-webkit-autofill, input:-webkit-autofill:hover, input:-webkit-autofill:focus, input:-webkit-autofill:active in CSS to style them.