# How to prevent InputAdornment from affecting TextField width in Material UI v5?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Is there a way to prevent `TextField` width from shrinking when adding `InputAdornment`?

**Image:**
[image]

**My current code:**

```
<TextField
  label="Username"
  {...formik.getFieldProps("username")}
  InputProps={{
    endAdornment: (
      <InputAdornment position="start">
        <Tooltip title="demo">
          <ErrorIcon sx={{ color: "orange" }} />
        </Tooltip>
      </InputAdornment>
    ),
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have just to change "***position***" property from **start** to **end**
Because when you specify start it's supposed to add margin on the right

Comment: The white gap got a little smaller, but issue isn't solved

Comment: then what was your issue exactly ?

Comment: Is there a way to get the blue background color to span the entire container? Looks weird like this

Comment: since you are using InputAdornment it's impossible i guess, so it reserves some space to fit the icon inside it

Comment: I see. Any idea how can I remove the blue fill instead then? So that the entire container remains white throughout. Btw, it only turns blue when I use autofill. If I were to manually type, the container doesn't turn blue.

Comment: i don't know why you get this blue background, maybe it has to do with some basic configurations you have, anyway this is a sample of my solution :
https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-chihiro-5zz6om?file=/demo.tsx

Comment: Thanks, but it seems like it's just a feature that Chrome has - Chrome changes the background color of the input when autofill is used as discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781549/removing-input-background-colour-for-chrome-autocomplete

Comment: ah okay then good luck with that

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
  in short: first boxSizing ensures that input paddings won't overflow,
  second ensures that input spans across the whole TextField,
  and WebkitBoxShadow ensures that autofill color remains transparent
*/

<TextField
  label="Username"
  {...formik.getFieldProps("username")}
  inputProps={{
    style: { 
      boxSizing: "border-box",
      WebkitBoxShadow: "0 0 0 1000px transparent inset"
    }
  }}
  InputProps={{
    style: {
      boxSizing: "border-box"
    },
    endAdornment: (
      <InputAdornment position="start">
        <Tooltip title="demo">
          <ErrorIcon sx={{ color: "orange" }} />
        </Tooltip>
      </InputAdornment>
    ),
  }}
/>
```