# Input css save browser

Tags: html, css

I have a doubt I have a text and password input on the login page, but when I save the password in the browser it has a different color, which property do I set to none

[image: It was for the input text and password to be gray]

Comment: Please include the HTML/CSS you're asking about, and clarify exactly what the problem is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing input background colour for Chrome autocomplete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781549/removing-input-background-colour-for-chrome-autocomplete)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be the browser autofill color. You can change it explicitly:

```
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover, 
input:-webkit-autofill:focus, 
input:-webkit-autofill:active{
    background-color: white !important;
}
```