# MUI TextField component changes background color to white when you choose one of the suggested autofill options

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

So, the problem is as in the title of this post.
Here's my component. It's just regular MUI text field:

```
 <TextField
          onChange={(e) => {
            handleSetUserData(e);
          }}
          sx={{ marginTop: "10px" }}
          fullWidth
          required
          variant="filled"
          label="Username"
          name="userName"
          inputProps={{ maxLength: 12 }}
        />
```

If I type manually color will stay the same. Any suggestions on how this could be fixed? All the text fields are also inside single FormControl btw.

Comment: its probably the browser autofill defaults, you can find a solution here that might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781549/removing-input-background-colour-for-chrome-autocomplete

Comment: @Breezer  that's not solved my problem, but that gave me the idea of where should I look for solution. And I found the way to fix that)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found the way to fix that.
With MUI 5 theme:

```
const myTheme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiTextField: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          input: {
            "&:-webkit-autofill": {
              WebkitBoxShadow: "0 0 0 100px #E0D98C <<<<(Your color here) inset",
              WebkitTextFillColor: "default",
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

It works for `variant="standart"` and `variant="outlined"` but works not that well for `variant="filled"`, cause it has some shadow effect on background. But I guess if you can tap into variant with the theme, it could be fixed. If not - just change the variant to outlined, as I did)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you it worked :)

You can use it in your sx also directly in textField

```
sx={{ 
'& .MuiOutlinedInput-input': { color: 'white',
 '&:-webkit-autofill': { WebkitBoxShadow: '0 0 0 100px #312E33 <<<<(Your color here) inset',
 WebkitTextFillColor: 'default', }, }, 
}}
```

---

Comment: Welcome! Thank you for contributing an answer. As a new user, you will need to gain reputation points to add comments to any question or answer. See the Stack Overflow help page about the [comment everywhere privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). The start of your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) reads more like a comment. However, comments should seek clarification of the question. An answer should provide a valid answer to part or all of the original question. Please edit your answer to only include the response to the original question. Thanks.