# Autofill input in dark mode with Tailwind

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, tailwind-css, darkmode

I had a problem with ugly colour in input after filling it with remembered password using Dark Mode.
In light mode it was yellow, not that bad.

[image]

[image]

I found some answers using `webkit-autofill` in SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781549/removing-input-background-colour-for-chrome-autocomplete), but had problem with implementing it in with tailwind `dark:`  prop and with sass in `global.scss` file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was to add this to global.scss file:

```
@layer components {
  .inputDarkModeOverride {
    &:-webkit-autofill {
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px #1c1c1d inset;
    }

    &:-webkit-autofill:hover {
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px #1c1c1d inset;
    }

    &:-webkit-autofill:focus {
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px #1c1c1d inset;
    }

    &:-webkit-autofill:active {
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px #1c1c1d inset;
    }
  }
}
```

and then `` className={`${styles.input} dark:inputDarkModeOverride`} `` in input props.