# How can I prevent chrome from overwriting my CSS properties defined on my username/password input fields when it uses the form auto-fill feature?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

I have been setting up a login form and because it is obvious to chrome, that the input fields are meant as a "login" to the website, chrome does its due diligence and offers to auto-fill the form with its known username and password account options.

However, when chrome does this, it does not honor the CSS properties (the properties I am most interested in are the "font-size" and "color").

I think the code below properly demonstrates the issue that I have been experiencing.

```css
.input-stack {
  margin: 50px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
}

input {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: white;
  background-color: #30A0A0;
}

.instruction {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.question {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-stack">
  <h2>Recreation Steps</h2>
  <ol type="1" class="instruction">
    <li>Click on the "Email Address" column below.</li>
    <li>If you have stored login accounts (google's password manager), chrome will prompt you with a pop-up asking which account to use.</li>
    <li>As you mouse over any of the options, notice how the "Email Address" input field is not honoring the 2rem font size that I have assigned to all input fields.</li>
    <li>Also you will notice that the font color and background color are changed if you select any of the accounts that google has provided.</li>
  </ol>
  <span class="question">So ... this leads me to my question: How do we force chrome to honor the CSS settings that I have given to the input fields (at all times and in any case)?</span>
  <label for="username">Email Address:</label>
  <input id="username" type="text" />
  <span>&nbsp;</span>
  <label for="password">Password:</label>
  <input id="password" type="password" />
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Removing input background colour for Chrome autocomplete?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2781549).

Comment: Mark your css settings with !important.

Comment: !important didn't work - apparently !important isn't as important as browser default behaviors.