# The dark/ light theming in an input does not work when autocomplete="on"

Tags: angular, bootstrap-5, darkmode

I have an input that I want to apply a light/dark theme to.

I implemented the input tag in Angular and I use Bootstrap to style the application.

### HTML

```html
<form [formGroup]="exportDialogueForm">
  <div class="form-floating mb-2">
    <input
      id="filename"
      formControlName="name"
      type="text"
      autofocus
      class="form-control"
      placeholder="{{ 'export.chooseFileName' | translate }}"
    />
    <label for="filename" class="form-label">
      {{"export.fileName" | translate}}
    </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

### Issue

As you can see in the image, when I focus on the input field, the `background-color` is not rendered in the `dark theme`. It looks like the `light theme`. If I set `autocomplete="off"` the `background-color` does not change and is displayed in the color of the selected theme.

[image: Dark theme in the input does not work]

[image: Dark theme works]

Unfortunately, I can't find a post with my error description.

I have tried it in following  browsers:

- Firefox
- Chrome and
- Edge

### Question

- What could be the cause of this error ?
- How to make sure that the browser always renders the correct
  theme?

Comment: <input type="text" name="username"  style = 'background: none ' value="">
you can handle it by css

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for your comment but it don't work for me.

Comment: Are you using [`prefers-color-scheme`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme) media query? Show us your stylesheet of the component in question.

Answer (score 0):

I was researching for a while and then came across a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14205976/15288591) that helped solve my problem in part.
The `background` of my input is now dark as desired when I switch to the `dark theme`. Unfortunately, the `background`is still displayed bright in the list of my saved entries.

Maybe one of you has a tip for me here.